# Optional Generic Type Inference

Tags: typescript

How to do a method infer type of function parameter but not specify its generic. Now is 'GET' | 'POST' but need only literal 'GET'

```
const func = <Params, Method extends "GET" | "POST" = "GET" | "POST">
({params, method}: {params?: Params, method: Method}) => {}

func<{qwe: 123}>
({method: 'GET'})
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZgVzMGBeGAeACgQwE44C2EANDALICmUAFiACYyUAeUlY9EMARAOICiAFW4wAPjywB5AMrC0PAXPHcps7gD4AUAAoA3gAd8RUjELU69AL4AuGAaPEA-LdwFiZM7Qa2qXqwEo0dTtLTU1EZAxdAEcAd0pbAEYAJgBmSy09TwtbAHJFXMt-IA)

```
const func = <Params, Method extends "GET" | "POST">
({params, method}: {params?: Params, method: Method}) => {}

func<{qwe: 123}>
({method: 'GET'})
```

This code requires explicit specification of generic method but I need to specify only params and method should be infer automatically from function parameters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More on type narrowing : https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html

Edit : Your problem might require you to use what we call a [function overload](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads). It might look promising from the outside, but from the little information I have from your question, I think you should rather focus on a different design system. Such as, for instance, not doing such a Generic use-case because this use-case is not "Generic". The Methods for an API Call haven't changed for a while, and won't change anytime soon. You're not searching for a "Generic", but rather, what you're doing is Narrowing a Fixed type.

---

I find your question slightly unclear. You should be careful about the [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/). You came here with a solution, but you should rather ask what your problem is.

Anyway, I think you need a typeguard. As far as I know, the only way to infer a type from a VALUE, except for a boolean, is to use a typeguard.

If you want to infer from the params TYPE (and not value), you need a function overload.

I give you an example of a Typeguard system that you can adapt to your use-case. Note that a real `typeguard` uses a different syntax, but it's the same trick than `type-narrowing` in the end, just a different syntax.

```js
type Methods = "GET" | "POST";
function func<Params>(method: Methods, params?: Params) {
    method;
    // (parameter) method: Methods

    if (method === "GET") {
        method;
        // (parameter) method: "GET"
    }

    method;
    // (parameter) method: Methods

    if (method === "GET") {
        method;
        // (parameter) method: "GET"
        return;
    }

    method;
    // (parameter) method: "POST"
}
```

For your information, here is a real "typeguard".

```js
type StringOrNumber = string | number;
function narrowStringOrNumber(value: StringOrNumber): value is string {
    if (typeof value === "string") {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

const a: StringOrNumber = "Hello";

a; // StringOrNumber
if (narrowStringOrNumber(a)) {
    a; // string
}
```